# How to get id of a thread?

Tags: java

Why does this project always show me Id 9? I mean, the output is like this:

```
FirstThread.txt
Id 9
<Some string read from the file>
...
...
SecondThread.txt
Id 9
<Some string read from the file>
```

I would estimate Id's to be different. This Id doesn't change even if I stop the project and run it again.

```
package parallelprogramming;

import java.lang.Thread;
import java.io.*;

public class Thrd extends Thread {

    public boolean readFile(String File)/* throws FileNotFoundException */ {
        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(File);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String s;
            try {
                while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(File);
                    System.out.println("Id " + this.getId());
                    System.out.println(s);
                }
                fr.close();
                return true;
            } catch (IOException IOE) {
                System.out.println("IOException caught!");
                return false;
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException FNFD) {
            System.out.println("File not found!");
            return false;
        }

    }
}



package parallelprogramming;

import java.awt.event.*;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class ParallelProgramming {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thrd FirstThread = new Thrd();
        Thrd SecondThread = new Thrd();

        Thrd CurrentThread = null;
        String File = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                File = "FirstThread.txt";
                CurrentThread = FirstThread;
            } else {
                File = "SecondThread.txt";
                CurrentThread = FirstThread;
            }
            while (!CurrentThread.isInterrupted()) {

                if (CurrentThread.readFile(File)) {

                    break;
                };
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see you create only 2 threads here:

```
    Thrd FirstThread = new Thrd();
    Thrd SecondThread = new Thrd();
```

Then you actually always use `FirstThread`:

```
CurrentThread = FirstThread;
```

So, only one thread is working and therefore the same ID is printed.

BTW there are naming conventions in java. All variables and methods start with small letter. Your capitalization is very confusing and makes your code less readable.

Answer (score 4):

Your code uses a single thread: the main thread. To start a thread, you need to

- extends Thread
- override its `run()` method
- instantiate your Thread subclass
- call its `start()` method

Or you need to

- create a Runnable
- pass it to a Thread constructor
- call the `start()` method of the Thread

This is clearly explained in [the tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html).

Extending Thread, adding a method (like `readFile()`) to the extending class, and calling it, will not invoke this method in another thread.

Side note: please respect the Java naming conventions. Methods and variables start with a lowercase letter.

Answer (score 1):

The `CurrentThread` variable is always initialized as `FirstThread`. Also even though you have extended from the Thread class the Threads are not started using the `start()` method. Therefore there isn't any threads running other than the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, `CurrentThread` is always `FirstThread`.

For another thing, you're not actually using those other threads as threads. You're just calling a method, as if they were any other objects.

Override `public void run()` in your `Thrd` class, and any code inside that will run in a separate thread. To start each thread, use `FirstThread.start();` and `SecondThread.start();`.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does this project always show me Id 9?

The mechanism by which thread ids are generated is *not specified* ... but if you look at [the code](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Thread.java.html) you will see that it is done using a simple counter that starts from zero.

So if you run the same application again, and the order of thread creation is the same, corresponding threads will have the same ids.

<sup>However, since this behaviour is unspecified, it would be unwise to rely on it.</sup>

So, in your example, you are getting the same thread ids because your application is creating them in the same order, from one run to the next.

> I would estimate [assume?] Id's to be different.

There is no basis for this assumption in the javadocs.  And in fact it is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo in your code, your are assigning the same thread every time.

Replace:

```
if (i % 2 == 0) {
            File = "FirstThread.txt";
            CurrentThread = FirstThread;
        } else {
            File = "SecondThread.txt";
            CurrentThread = FirstThread;
        }
```

By

```
if (i % 2 == 0) {
            File = "FirstThread.txt";
            CurrentThread = FirstThread;
        } else {
            File = "SecondThread.txt";
            CurrentThread = SecondThread;
        }
```

However, maybe you should consider to use ThreadName to identify your threads: [JavaDoc for Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread%28java.lang.String%29)